# Resolve axios to a variable instead of doing everything in the callback

Tags: javascript, promise, callback, async-await, axios

So I am 99% sure this cannot be done, but humor me for a moment. Consider the two functions:

```
function doAjaxCall(fieldTocheckAgainst, currentField, value) {
  axios.get(
    window.location.origin +
    '/api/clinic/'+window.id+'/patient/'+window.secondId+'/field-validation',
    {
      params: {
        field_to_check_against: fieldTocheckAgainst,
        current_field: currentField,
        value: moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      }
    }
  ).then((result) => {
    return result.data
  });
}

async function resolveAjaxCall(fieldTocheckAgainst, currentField, value) {
  const result = await doAjaxCall(fieldTocheckAgainst, currentField, value)

  console.log(result);
}
```

I am attempting to resolve the axios ajax call into a variable based on what I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43371957/1270259) and it doesn't work. I get `undefined`.

I understand when it comes to callbacks, everything has to be done in the callback, but is there no way, with async and await to resolve the promise to a variable as I am attempting to do, to then use said variable else where?

**Or am I just going to be stuck with callbacks?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see with your code is that `axios.get()` returns a `Promise`, but you aren't returning that promise from `doAjaxCall`. Promises are values, and they need to be passed around to be used.

Just add `return` before `axios.get` and that should give you the result you want.

--

On the question of "returning" from a promise - Async functions always return promises, even if you don't include a return statement. If your async function ends in the statement `return true`, it's actually returning a `Promise` that resolves to `true`. As you guessed in your original post, there is no way to pull a value out of a promise and into synchronous code.

Comment: that worked, accept now I get: `Promise {<pending>}` and then
`{message: "Date cannot be greator then today.", isError: true}` Is there something I am missing such that I only get the object and not the promise then the object?

Comment: Async functions always return promises - even if you don't include a return statement. If your async function ends in the statement `return true`, it's actually returning a Promise that resolves to `true`. As you guessed in your original post, there is no way to pull value out of a promise and into synchronous code.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `return` statement in your `doAjaxCall` function, and you also need to treat the function as promise. It should be the following:

```
function doAjaxCall(fieldTocheckAgainst, currentField, value) {
    return axios.get(
        window.location.origin + '/api/clinic/'+window.id+'/patient/'+window.secondId+'/field-validation',
        {
            params: {
            field_to_check_against: fieldTocheckAgainst,
            current_field: currentField,
            value: moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        return result.data
    });
}

async function resolveAjaxCall(fieldTocheckAgainst, currentField, value) {

    const result = doAjaxCall(fieldTocheckAgainst, currentField, value).then(data = {
        console.log(data);
    })

}
```

Comment: The problem is I am trying to avoid using the `.then` because the `resolveAjaxCall` should return just the result of the ajax call. I assume there is no way around that?